# How to set Normal Texture Scale Value as a Vector ([1, -1])

Tags: rust, 3d, asset-pipeline, gltf, rust-crates

I'm using the gltf-json crate for this job. I want to be able to change the normal texture scale to `[1, -1]` to an asset that comes with `[1, 1]`, however, the scale field is of type `f32`.

```
pub struct NormalTexture {
    pub index: Index<Texture>,
    pub scale: f32,
    pub tex_coord: u32,
    pub extensions: Option<NormalTexture>,
    pub extras: Extras,
}
```

Does anyone know if there's a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is based in the glTF specification, which [requires a scalar value for `material.normalTextureInfo.scale`](https://registry.khronos.org/glTF/specs/2.0/glTF-2.0.html#_material_normaltextureinfo_scale). No valid tool will be able to work around that, other than writing `extras` or a custom extension to the file.

An aside, I would note that depending on the client loading this file, the correct client *interpretation* of `scale = 1` might turn out to be `[1, -1]`, based on the UV conventions of the engine, presence of vertex tangents, etc. This [occurs in the three.js glTF loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/4736375b488050dcdef9ba8fc9a3e73e181611df/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js#L3409-L3415), for example.